# Can liquibase use github as source of changeLog files?

Tags: github, integration-testing, liquibase, changelog

Consider project with different language modules that use same database. Database is controlled by liquibase. Liquibase changeLog files placed in special github repository. So every developer could download it and run locally to keep local instance of database in actual state.

Often developers use inmemory database like H2 for testing and liquibase rebuilds database structure every test run. To keep testing database in actual state every developer need to download changeLogs and put in their modules manually. But sometimes he could miss that somebody else changed database structure, so his tests should fail, but will pass. This is more actual for testing in CI.

Could liquibase download changelogs automatically from internet source? Could it use private github repositories? Could it use some property like changeLogFile for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

May I confirm some assumptions?  It sounds you have a team of developers all commiting liquibase database changes and you want to be able to automatically deploy in a CI/CD process?

Thanks,

Ronak
Liquibase Developer Evangelist

Comment: Thank you for answer! Not yet, but I have such idea. I investigate such possibility.

Comment: I agree with dbf below.  The idea is that liquibase can fit into existing CI/CD pipeline automation.  So we would suggest to instrument all the files the way you want it on the server where you will run liquibase.  Its not for liquibase to decide what repository you want to use or what ci/cd tool to use, or become an scm or ci/cd tool.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase can't run changelogs placed into some remote git repo. But in your CI you can setup such thing: if there is a pull-request from branch 'feature' to branch 'master' automatically:

1. Before tests are executed checkout branch 'feature'
   and merge 'master' there
2. Apply all changelogs
3. Run tests after it

So if another developer change DB structure and commit it into master tests in 'feature' branch will be executed with latest DB structure.